# Everyone Accesses Successfully with High Probability

Tags: probability

Say there are $n$ processes requiring one file per second. At each second, each process accesses the file with probability $p$ independently. The file can be accessed if and only if there is exactly one process requiring it at the same second. Whether one process successfully accesses the file at some time does not affect its access in the future. I'd like to ask how many seconds are required to guarantee that all processes succeed to access the file with probability at least $1-\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: It depends on whether the processes who have already accessed the file continue to do so in the future, or not. Either way, this looks like a discrete time Markov chain with states $\{0, 1, 2, ..., n\}$, and the only transitions are $i\rightarrow i$ and $i\rightarrow i+1$. The time to go from $i$ to $i+1$ is independent of the past and is a geometric random variable with a certain success probability $p_i$. This makes the mean and variance of the time to finish easier to compute than the PMF of the finishing time or the PMF of the current state at time $k$ (which is determined by $P^k$).